# How to disable the update request in Opera?

Tags: opera

Since the update to Opera version 66.0.3515.103, I receive permanent a request before start of Opera.

> A new version of Opera is available. Install update now?

But I don't like to install an update after update every time.

It is not the question how to disable the automatic update. Things for that like

- `...\opera.exe --disable-update`
- `...\launcher.exe --disable-update`
- move or rename of `opera_autoupdate.exe`

are realized already.

However how can be deactivated the *update request* in Opera?

Answer (score 0):

Opera installs a *service* to handle its updating requests, much like Mozilla does with Firefox, but less transparently, I'm afraid.

Open services.msc via the Run command box, search for an entry named Opera Update or some such thing, and disable it.

Just know that the service will enable itself again when you manually update your copy of Opera, because it comes with the install bundle, and is reinstalled alongside the executable with each new program update...

Comment: I run services.msc. But there is no entry about "Opera Update". services.msc does not provide a search utility. But it's indirect possible with: Action -> Export list ... -> services.txt. Open services.txt in notepad and search "Opera". But no success.

Answer (score 0):

In the current Opera directory:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet\Opera\66.0.3515.103
```

are contained these files, among others:

- `installer.exe`
- `installer_helper_64.exe`
- `installer_helper_lib.dll`

All these 3 files I have moved to a temporary folder `_removed`.
After that the update request was switched off.
Maybe removing one of these 3 files would be sufficient.